# Reading strings with VS2010 SerialPort control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6, serial-port

I am reading a string from a servo drive that is transmitted as characters.  When I read the string with my old VB6 programs using the MSComm control I got individual values from 0-255 for each byte (character).  When I read the same string with the VS2010 SerialPort control, I get 0-127.  Any value over 127 returns as 63.

Comment: Is there any code you could show us? The new VS2010 code for instance?

Comment: What language are you using is VS2010? Might be good to add that as a tag.

Comment: I am using Visual Basic.  The SerialPort function works fine till I receive a character >127 then I get a 63 (?) as a return.  I have been using the serialport.encoding function to try and change the encoding to something that recognizes all 256 characters (Maybe Western European (ISO)) but I haven't been able to get the correct code to change the encoding.  Here is the code snippet...pretty simple

Comment: Dim AL As Integer
        WordIn = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        AL = Len(WordIn)
        For k = 1 To AL
            InWord(k) = Asc(Mid(WordIn, k, 1))
        Next

Comment: Figured out issue.  inserted this code...                                SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default     Now I get 0 to 255.  Thanks to another blogger (lost link)